# How do I connect Crystal reports to multiple database?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, crystal-reports

I have a webpage which has a drop-down. In the drop-down there is a list of databases from a server. On selecting the drop-down document numbers are shown and we can click and generate crystal report.

My problem is I have given data-source for one database in the crystal report. Suppose I select other databases. How can I connect to the report for multiple databases?

Any inputs will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using CR designer or Visual Studio to make your reports? Because there is a connection section in the field explorer window. Generally, it is not recommend to connect to multiple DB. Even if you are using for example 2 or more stored procedures for your report, you can complicate your life if they don't have a common key.

Answer (score 0):

The below is what we use, it should work for you. Basically you have to make sure that for every table the report accesses (or command, or view, etc.), the connection is set. I'm not aware of a way to set it only on the main report.

```
// create a ReportDocument
using (ReportDocument reportDoc = new ReportDocument())
{
    reportDoc.Load(path); // path to your .rpt file

    // get the connection string you want to use
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder conInfo = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder("<your connection string>");

    Tables crTables = reportDoc.Database.Tables;
    int tablecounter = 0;
    foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table crTable in crTables)
    {
        CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo logonInfo = crTable.LogOnInfo;

        logonInfo.ConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo()
        {
            DatabaseName = conInfo.InitialCatalog,
            ServerName = conInfo.DataSource
        };
        if (conInfo.IntegratedSecurity)
        {
            logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = true;
        }
        else
        {
            logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = conInfo.UserID;
            logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = conInfo.Password;
        }

        crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(logonInfo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I will try this out. In the connection string, I will put connection to only one database?

Comment: right. You should fill in the connection string for the correct database based on the selection from your drop down. You'll have to run through this again whenever it changes and you want to create a report.

Comment: And where will i put the table or view?